# What is the nearest equivalent to Java's Character.isDefined, in .NET?

Tags: c#, java, .net

Java has a [Character.isDefined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDefined%28char%29) method, but there's no equivalent on the char class in .NET.

I'm aware that [Microsoft's old Java libraries have this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa986087%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but I don't want to depend on that library if I can avoid it.

Is there a built in equivalent in .NET somewhere? Or does calling all the available .is* methods combinatorially produce the same result? (e.g. char.IsLetter(x) || char.IsSymbol(x) etc....)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try with

```
int utf32 = 0x1FFFF;
string surrogate = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(utf32);
var isDefined = char.GetUnicodeCategory(surrogate, 0) != UnicodeCategory.OtherNotAssigned;
```

You can use `char.GetUnicodeCategory(char)` directly if you have a character from the base BMP.

Note that each version of .NET supports different releases of Unicode, so what it will return is dependant of the version of Unicode used by the current version of .NET/current OS.

Comment: Excellent, this looks like it reproduces the behaviour very closely, thanks!

Comment: char.TryParse(firstChar.ToString(),out firstChar) would this give apt result?

Comment: @RohitGarg `char.TryParse` doesn't do checks on the Unicode "validity" of a `char`. It simply converts a `string` to a `char`. It is quite useless. `char.TryParse("A", out ch)` returns `'A'`, but clearly so would more directly `"A"[0] == 'A'`